# Допустимо ли употребление словосочетания "звериный холод"?

Tags: семантика, паронимы

Допустимо ли употребление словосочетания "звериный холод" или строго "зверский"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Звериный холод*** ― допустимое сочетание, но применяется оно значительно реже, чем ***зверский холод***.

Дело в том, что у прилагательного ***звериный*** основным является притяжательное значение, а у прилагательного **зверский** оба значения переносные.

Из словаря

**ЗВЕРСКИЙ**,  Разг. 1. Жестокий, свирепый, дикий. З-ое убийство. З-ая выходка. З-ие мучения. **2. Очень сильный, чрезвычайный в своём проявлении**. З. аппетит. З-ая жара. З-ая скука.

**ЗВЕРИНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. к Зверь (1 зн.). З. вой. З-ая тропа. З-ое чутьё. З-ые следы. 2. **Жестокий, свирепый, дикий.** З-ые нравы. З-ые законы. 3. **Разг. Очень сильный, чрезвычайный в своём проявлении**. З-ая тоска. З. эгоизм.

Примеры:

Теплый день наконец, а в проклятом дежурном склепе **звериный холод.** [Александр Болдырев. Осадная запись (блокадный дневник) (1941-1948)]

**Зверский холод**, показалось им, стоял в опустелой квартире, лучше было не раздеваться. [Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Части 1-2 (1927)]

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что такое словосочетание употребляется либо по недоразумению, либо намеренно - для красного словца (собака порылась и т. п.). У варианта "зверский" смысловое обоснование есть: "холод зверствует". У выражения же со "звериный" (= холод, свойственный зверям - бессмыслица) его нет.

Answer (score 1):

Словосочетание "звериный холод" не подходит к описанию температуры воздуха. Во всяком случае, такое описание звучит неестественно и неэлегантно.

В то же время, употребление этого оборота возможно в переносном смысле слова:
"её ненавидящие глаза источали звериный холод".  Не скажу, что этот оборот стилистически безупречен, но он допустим.

Comment: В этом примере, скорее, работают ассоциации с выражениями "холодный взгляд" и "смотрит зверем". Без упоминания "глаз" смысл рассыпается.

Comment: С этим я согласен.